# Почему в этом предложении необходимы запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть вот такое предложение: Исстари на Оке (1) там (2) где вливалась в неё холодная прозрачная речка Тарка (3) на древних торговых путях существовала переправа (4) на которой перевозчиком в начале XVI века был некий отшельник Павел (5) отчего возникшее селение и получило название «Павлов перевоз».
Цифры, на месте которых в предложении должны стоять запятые: 1,2,3,4,5. Почему нужны запятые на цифрах 1,2? с остальными цифрами всё понятно.

Comment: Три однородных обстоятельства: времени - исстари на Оке, места - где вливалась, и направления - там на которой...был. Там, где - всегда запятая

Comment: Однородные?  Там разные есть: неоднородные (места и времени) и три однородных (на Оке, там, где), оформленные как последовательное уточнение.

Comment: Однородные в смысле все эти слова и группы слов относятся к слову переправа, являются предикатами - условиями ограничивающими не глагол, а понятие существование. Однородные в смысле связанные с одинаковой предикативной позиции, потому они должны быть обособлены запятыми, каждое в свой домик, чтобы отделить их друг от друга. Запятые отделяют однородные друг от друга. В этом смысл запятых. Хотя, может я неверно трактую слова однородные и предикат?

Comment: В грамматике есть понятие обстоятельства, как и в жизни. Из толкового словаря: событие, факт, сопутствующие чему-л., связанные с чем-л.; та или иная сторона дела, события. Существенное о. Главные, второстепенные обстоятельства. ГРАММ. Второстепенный член предложения, указывающий время, место, образ действия и т.п. У нас обстоятельства времени (когда) и места (где?). Если отвечают на один и тот же вопрос, то однородные.